# How can I select those element which have no text children

Tags: xml, xpath

In document below I am trying to get those element have no text child.
but every effort get nothing.

```
<a>
      <b>
         <c> this is nice place </c>
      </b>

      <d> 
         <e> where this place is </e>
         <f> this place is very close to us</f>
      </d>

      <g> 
        <h/>
      </g>

     <i/>
</a>
```

Comment: Well, show us what you have tried?  You mean element <h>?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
//*[not(node())]
```

[Test query here](http://www.xpathtester.com/colored/93dd37f17ad09911c8b058fb393af298)

Comment: I need to select <g> because <g> have no text child but this XPATH selecting only those child having no text in it like <h/> rather this select <h/> this should select <g> or any having no text child.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheet that copies empty elements (immediate children of `a`) and their children, if there's not a single text node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <empty>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(node()/text())]"/>
    </empty>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<empty>
  <g>
    <h />
  </g>
  <i />
</empty>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want all the children of `a` which have no text nodes?

```
/a/element()[not(.//text())]
```